# How do I do a contains expression in a nested object?

Tags: jmespath

this is my json

```json
{
  "items": [
      "top": {
        "first": "test",
        "second": {
          "third": "test",
        },
        ...
```

This returns all items where `top.first` contains `test`:

```
items[?contains(top.first, `test`)]
```

This returns an error:

```
items[?contains(top.second.third, `test`)]
```

> TypeError: contains() expected argument 1 to be type (string | array) but received type null instead.

This works with a explict `==`, but for some reason `contains()` is throwing the above error

```
items[?top.second.third == `test`]
```

How do I query one level lower here?

Comment: Does all the `items`, without any exception, have a `top.second.third`? I guess this is what the error you have is about.

Comment: Also, could you please make sure you provide a valid JSON, for the moment being you have a property in an array, which is not a valid JSON, sadly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I suspect: you do have some `items` in your JSON array that either do not have the `top.second` property or do not have the `top.second.third` property.

So, here is my base JSON to try to reproduce your issue, where you can see I do have the three cases:

- one element with no `second` property
- one element with a `second` property, but no `third` property nested in `second`
- one element with a `second` property and a `third` property nested in `second`

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "top": {
        "first": "test"
      }
    },
    {
      "top": {
        "first": "test",
        "second": {}
      }
    },
    {
      "top": {
        "first": "test",
        "second": {
          "third": "test"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With all this, we can demonstrate that it is fairly easy to achieve what you want, since we just have to first check that all those property do exists with a simple `[?top.second.third]` before adding our `contains` statement.

Ending with the query:

```
items[?top.second.third && contains(top.second.third, `test`)]
```

That yields, as we would expect:

```json
[
  {
    "top": {
      "first": "test",
      "second": {
        "third": "test"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This was it. One of the items did not have the property. That error message had me so off track I thought it was syntax. And I could find no specific examples for a contains() statement at this depth so I assumed it wasn't supported or something.